# deploy webservice at different contextroot from webapp

Tags: java, web-services, java-ee-7, wildfly-8

I have two webapps in the same wildfly 8 server. Both are deployed at contextroot /, and use different host-configuration.

However, i have one webservice included in both webapps, but wildfly deploys both of them at the same contextroot, and hence when i deploy the applications, one inherently fails because its webservice name already collides with the other webservice for the other webapp that was deployed first.

I want to deploy the webservice on every webapp at different contextroots, while maintaining each webapps contextroot at /.

I have looked at the JBossWS guide, and this does not help.

```
@Webservice(name = "service", serviceName = "web")
public class MyWebservice{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a Webservice outside of the contextRoot of a WebApp. 
Also you cannot have two WebApps under the same contextRoot.

So you could perhaps deploy your two webapps without the webservice under two different contextRoots - but expose EJB-interfaces.... to your new third application which consumes the EJB-interfaces and exposes the Webservice.

Comment: All webservices maintain some kind of configuration for the webapp. And even though it is the same endpoint in terms of interface-definition, the data it receives are specific to whichever webapp it is currently running within. So no, i cannot move it to an ejb-webservice (which i know the webservice-contextroot applies)